# Is there any Shortcut associated with key '2'(keycode=50) in Flatmenu?

Tags: wxpython

I am trying to develop application displaying a FlatMenu,toolbar and the following panel.In toolbar i have put a textctrl. When i am trying to enter key '2' its not getting typed.I tried to debug code its printing keycode in log but in textctrl its not getting typed.Apart from '2' all other key i am able to enter.

**Code**

```
import wx
import os
import sys
import webbrowser
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel as scrolled
import wx.lib.agw.flatmenu as FM
wx.Log.SetLogLevel(0)


class MainPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent,style=wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)                       

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "FlatMenu Demo")
        self.toolbar = self.CreateToolBar()
        self.textctrl = wx.TextCtrl( self.toolbar, wx.ID_ANY, value='',size=(100, -1))
        self.textctrl.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_UP, self.HandleKeyPress)
        self.createToolbarItem(0,1,"connect", "new_icons/connect.png", self.stopLiveUpdate)
        self.toolbar.DoInsertTool(1,2, '', wx.Bitmap('new_icons/install_app.png'))
        self.toolbar.DoInsertTool(2,3, '', wx.Bitmap('new_icons/uninstall.png'))
        self.toolbar.InsertControl(3,self.textctrl)
        self.toolbar.Realize()
        self.CreateMenu()
        self.panel = MainPanel(self)
        self.PanelSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.PanelSizer.Add( self.menubar, 0,wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_LEFT | wx.EXPAND )
        self.PanelSizer.Add( self.toolbar, 0, wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_LEFT | wx.EXPAND )
        self.PanelSizer.Add( self.panel, 1, wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_LEFT | wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.PanelSizer)
        self.Layout()

    def HandleKeyPress(self,e):
        keycode = e.GetKeyCode()
        print keycode
        if keycode==50:
            print 'entered'
            e.Skip()            
        else:
            print 'not entered'
            return  
        e.Skip()

    def CreateMenu(self):
        self.menubar = FM.FlatMenuBar(self,-1)

        file = FM.FlatMenu()
        conn = FM.FlatMenu()
        help = FM.FlatMenu()
        app  = FM.FlatMenu()
        log = FM.FlatMenu()
        file.Append(1,"&Start Stream")
        file.Append(2,"&Stop stream")
        type = FM.FlatMenu()
        self.type1 = FM.FlatMenuItem(type, 3, "Type1", wx.ITEM_CHECK)
        type.AppendItem(self.type1)
        self.type2 = FM.FlatMenuItem(type, 4, "Type2", wx.ITEM_CHECK)
        type.AppendItem(self.type2)
        file.AppendMenu(5, "Emulator &Tuner-Type",type)
        self.quit = file.Append(6, "&Exit \tAlt+F4", "Quit the Application")
        conn.Append(7,"&Connect")
        conn.Append(8,"&Disconnect")
        conn.Append(9,"&Power Off")
        conn.Append(10,"&Shut Down")
        app.Append(11,"&Install App")
        app.Append(12,"&Transfer Files")
        app.Append(13,"&Run App")
        app.Append(14,"&Kill App")
        app.Append(15,"&Update App")
        app.Append(16,"&Uninstall App")
        log.Append(17,"&Save Log")
        log.Append(18,"&Clear Log")
        log.Append(19,"&Refresh Log")
        help.Append(20,"&Home")
        help.Append(21,"&Google")
        help.Append(22,"&User Manual     \tF1")
        help.Append( 23, "&About")

        self.menubar.Append(file, "&Start")
        self.menubar.Append(conn, "&Connection")
        self.menubar.Append(app, "&App")
        self.menubar.Append(log, "&Log")
        self.menubar.Append(help, "&Help")
        self.Bind(FM.EVT_FLAT_MENU_SELECTED, self.OnQuit, id=5)
        self.Bind(FM.EVT_FLAT_MENU_SELECTED,self.launchGoogle,id=21)

    def OnQuit(self,e=None):
        self.Destroy()

    def launchGoogle(self,event=None):
        webbrowser.open('http://google.com')

    def startLiveUpdate(self, event):
        self.createToolbarItem(0,1,"connect", "new_icons/connect.png", self.stopLiveUpdate)

    def stopLiveUpdate(self, event):
        self.createToolbarItem(0,1,"disconnect", "new_icons/disconnected.png", self.startLiveUpdate)


    def createToolbarItem(self,pos,id,label,imageName,method=None):
        self.toolbar.RemoveTool(id)
        self.pos = self.toolbar.GetToolsCount()
        self.toolbar.DoInsertTool(pos,id, label, wx.Bitmap(imageName))
        self.toolbar.Realize()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, method, id=id)


app = wx.App(0)

frame = MyFrame(None)
app.SetTopWindow(frame)
frame.Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I just tried this code verbatim (with different pictures, of course), and it worked. Are you still having this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted didn't work well at all on my system, as a result of how you were trying to use a sizer on a panel that didn't have any children. I modified the code a bit to get it to look better for me (Windows 7, wxPython 2.9.4) and then traced the issue to how you are setting up the FlatMenu. Do you know there is a FlatMenu.py demo?

https://github.com/crankycoder/wxPython-2.9.2.4/blob/master/wxPython/demo/agw/FlatMenu.py

Taking some ideas from that I added just a few entries to the FlatMenu and it is working for the number 2, so I am assuming you were using a special ID (generally the recommendation is to use wx.ID_ANY rather than hard-coded IDs, since some IDs have special effects). Please check the commented-out code and see how you would continue on with modifying it to work.

Also another big problem that could have eventually caused issues was you were over-riding reserved words like 'file' and 'type'.

```
import wxversion
import wx
import os
import sys
import webbrowser
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel as scrolled
import wx.lib.agw.flatmenu as FM
wx.Log.SetLogLevel(0)


class MainPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent,style=wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)                       

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "FlatMenu Demo")
        self.panel = MainPanel(self)
        self.PanelSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        #self.toolbar = self.CreateToolBar(style=wx.TB_FLAT|wx.WANTS_CHARS)
        self.toolbar = wx.ToolBar(self.panel, style=wx.TB_FLAT)
        self.textctrl = wx.TextCtrl( self.toolbar, wx.ID_ANY, value='',size=(100, -1), style=wx.WANTS_CHARS)
        self.textctrl.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, self.HandleKeyPress)
        self.toolbar.DoInsertTool(0,1,"connect", wx.Bitmap("gear_blue.png"))
        self.toolbar.DoInsertTool(1,2, '', wx.Bitmap('gear_blue.png'))
        self.toolbar.DoInsertTool(2,3, '', wx.Bitmap('tools.png'))
        t = self.toolbar.InsertControl(3,self.textctrl)
        self.toolbar.Realize()
        self.CreateMenu()

        self.PanelSizer.Add( self.menubar, 0, wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_LEFT | wx.EXPAND )
        self.PanelSizer.Add( self.toolbar, 0, wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_LEFT | wx.EXPAND )
        #self.PanelSizer.Add( self.panel, 1, wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_LEFT | wx.EXPAND)
        self.panel.SetSizer(self.PanelSizer)
        self.panel.Layout()

    def HandleKeyPress(self,e):
        keycode = e.GetKeyCode()
        print keycode
        if keycode==50:
            print 'entered'
            #return
            #e.Skip()            
        else:
            print 'not entered'
            #return  
        e.Skip()

    def CreateMenu(self):
        self.menubar = FM.FlatMenuBar(self.panel,-1)

        f = FM.FlatMenu()
        conn = FM.FlatMenu()
        h = FM.FlatMenu()
        app  = FM.FlatMenu()
        log = FM.FlatMenu()


        item = FM.FlatMenuItem(f, wx.ID_ANY, "&Start Stream\tCtrl+S", "Start Stream", wx.ITEM_NORMAL)
        f.AppendItem(item)

        item = FM.FlatMenuItem(f, wx.ID_ANY, "&Stop Stream\tCtrl+S", "Stop Stream", wx.ITEM_NORMAL)
        f.AppendItem(item)
        """
        #f.Append(2,"&Stop stream")
        t = FM.FlatMenu()
        self.type1 = FM.FlatMenuItem(t, 3, "Type1", wx.ITEM_CHECK)
        t.AppendItem(self.type1)
        self.type2 = FM.FlatMenuItem(t, 4, "Type2", wx.ITEM_CHECK)
        t.AppendItem(self.type2)
        f.AppendMenu(5, "Emulator &Tuner-Type",t)
        self.quit = f.Append(6, "&Exit \tAlt+F4", "Quit the Application")
        conn.Append(7,"&Connect")
        conn.Append(8,"&Disconnect")
        conn.Append(9,"&Power Off")
        conn.Append(10,"&Shut Down")
        app.Append(11,"&Install App")
        app.Append(12,"&Transfer Files")
        app.Append(13,"&Run App")
        app.Append(14,"&Kill App")
        app.Append(15,"&Update App")
        app.Append(16,"&Uninstall App")
        log.Append(17,"&Save Log")
        log.Append(18,"&Clear Log")
        log.Append(19,"&Refresh Log")
        h.Append(20,"&Home")
        h.Append(21,"&Google")
        h.Append(22,"&User Manual     \tF1")
        h.Append( 23, "&About")
        """
        self.menubar.Append(f, "&Start")

        self.menubar.Append(conn, "&Connection")
        self.menubar.Append(app, "&App")
        self.menubar.Append(log, "&Log")
        self.menubar.Append(h, "&Help")
        #self.Bind(FM.EVT_FLAT_MENU_SELECTED, self.OnQuit, id=5)
        #self.Bind(FM.EVT_FLAT_MENU_SELECTED,self.launchGoogle,id=21)

    def OnQuit(self,e=None):
        self.Destroy()

    def launchGoogle(self,event=None):
        webbrowser.open('http://google.com')

    def startLiveUpdate(self, event):
        self.createToolbarItem(0,1,"connect", "gear_blue.png", self.stopLiveUpdate)

    def stopLiveUpdate(self, event):
        self.createToolbarItem(0,1,"disconnect", "tools.png", self.startLiveUpdate)


    def createToolbarItem(self,pos,id,label,imageName,method=None):
        self.toolbar.RemoveTool(id)
        self.pos = self.toolbar.GetToolsCount()
        self.toolbar.DoInsertTool(pos,id, label, wx.Bitmap(imageName))
        self.toolbar.Realize()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, method, id=id)


app = wx.App(0)

frame = MyFrame(None)
app.SetTopWindow(frame)
frame.Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Actually the more I look at it, the problem arises when you add the sub-menu (you are using AppendMenu, but could be using AppendSubMenu, though it just calls AppendMenu anyway). So the problem seems like a bug in the widget, sorry.